# Statement in probability

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $\varphi_L$ be some random variable dependent on a parameter $L$ and consider the following statement,

Statement (a) : There exists a constant $C >0$ such that $ \, \, \, \, \mathbb{P}(\forall L \in \mathbb{N}, \, \,  \, \, \varphi_L \leq C) = 1$.

Statement (b) : There exists a subsequence $\varphi_{L_i}$, a constant $K >0$ and an increasing function $\phi(i)$ satisfying $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \phi(i) = \infty$ such that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$\, \, \, \, \,
\mathbb{P} (\varphi_{L_{i}} \geq \phi(i)) \geq K.
$

Is it true that if statement (a) does not hold, then does statement (b) hold?

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is false. A 'random variabl dependent on parameter' is in fact a sequence of random variables, or a random process. Now, what if exactly $\varphi_1$ has unbounded support while $\varphi_2$, $\varphi_3$, $\ldots$ are bounded a.s. Then both (a) and (b) are false.

Comment: The question is: does "(a) is false" imply "(b)" ?